# MSTest /runconfig - No tests are run

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest, testrunconfig

I am running MSTest.exe without any problems if I do not specify a /runconfig file.  However, as soon as I specify the config file (which is the exact same file, but in a different location), the test outputs the following:

```
Loading C:\myapp\conf\unit-test-local\App.config...
C:\myapp\conf\unit-test-local\App.config
C:\myapp\conf\unit-test-local\App.config
```

If I run the command *without* the /runconfig, it runs properly and displays:

```
Loading C:\myapp\src\UnitTests\bin\Debug\UnitTests.dll...
```

It's definitely finding the App.config file because if I purposely type a bad file name, it complains.  The App.config in my conf directory is an exact copy of the one that is used if I do not specify the /runconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/runconfig` is not referring to the `app.config` file but on the [*.Testrunconfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#runconfig)

This file contains several settings regarding the way you want your tests to run.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Ok, so how do I swap out the actual configuration file that it chooses to use?

Comment: What is the version of your Visual Studio? This setting is no longer used from vs2010. It is replaced by the *testsettings.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and I'm just trying to swap out the location of the application's .config file at run time, rather than use the one that gets generated by the checked out build from svn.

Comment: I am not sure you can do that so simply. You could maybe use the [DeploymentItemAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It will deploy your file (app.config) at the build output folder, but I am not sure that this will work.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I may just add a build step to my continuous integration server that overwrites the config file as checked out by svn.